# How to add Gitlab-token to sourcetree?

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I try to commit a file to a gitlab repo, but I receive

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false
> --no-optional-locks push -v --tags origin main:main  remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.  fatal: unable to access
> 'https://gitlab.server.com/Edna/myproject.git/': The requested URL
> returned error: 403  Pushing to
> https://gitlab.server.com/Edna/myproject.git  Mit Fehlern
> abgeschlossen, siehe oben.

Therefore, I got a personal access token from my gitlab operator like:

> abcde-aC5unFT3ELQT-VMZKSpV

How do I use this PAT? How to enable this in **sourcetree** git desktop tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local repository is configured to use HTTPS instead of git over ssh. The output of `git remote -v` should verify this. You will see something similar to:

```
origin  https://gitlab.server.com/Edna/myproject.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.server.com/Edna/myproject.git (push)
```

Follow the instructions to [create and add your SSH key to your GitLab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html).

Then, use a SSH remote repository for origin.

```
$ git remote rename origin https-origin
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.server.com:Edna/myproject.git
```

Then, try your git command.